# Excel VBA Macro: User Defined Type Not Defined STILL AFTER I added reference

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

Thanks everyone for your help and sorry that I couldn't reply earlier. My problem is still there
I read the link you posted there and update the original codes I found. (Maybe in a wrong way because it does not work and I really know very little about codings
Here are the codes I tried to use. can you help me find the problems? Thanks a lot!

```
Sub CopyCommentsToExcel()

'Create in Word vba
'set a reference to the Excel object library
Dim theApp As Object
On Error Resume Next
MacScript "tell application id ""com.microsoft.Excel"" to activate"
Err.Clear
'On Error Goto problem ' you need to set this up
Set theApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
' just be careful
If theApp Is Nothing Then
  Debug.Print "theApp Is Nothing"
Else
  Debug.Print TypeName(theApp)
  ' get on with what you need to do
End If


Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add ' create a new workbook
With xlWB.Worksheets(1)
    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Comments.Count
        .Cells(i, 1).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Initial
        .Cells(i, 2).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Range
        .Cells(i, 3).Formula = Format(ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Date, "dd/MM/yyyy")
    Next i
End With
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

--------updated above——————————

I'm completely new to VBA (or all coding things). Recently I tried to export all comments in a word document to an excel document. When doing so by following codes online (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/export-word-review-comments-in-excel/54818c46-b7d2-416c-a4e3-3131ab68809c?page=1), it keeps telling me "User Defined Type Not Defined" and pops back to `Dim xlApp As Excel.Application`
But I did set a VBA reference to "Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library".
I have no idea what is wrong and probably have made some silly mistakes (like I didn't save the code properly?). Could anyone help? Thanks in advance.

[Added reference already](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOTDP.png)

Comment: Are you using macOS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64090595/478884

Comment: Yes, I use macOS. And I cannot find the usual "save", "tools" as in guide for windows TAT

Comment: As the link in the comment above says COM Automation has been broken on the Mac versions of Office for some years now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save Word document using Excel VBA on Mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64071777/how-to-save-word-document-using-excel-vba-on-mac-os)

Comment: Thanks Tim, Timothy and Eugene. I tried the codes in the link you posted and combined them with the original codes I found. But it still doesn't work. Maybe I did it in the wrong way and I've updated the details above. Could u plz help me check what is wrong? Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be a proper "Answer," but I do not have enough reputation to post a comment asking for more information, so this will have to do.

The Answer referenced by Tim Williams describes problems related to Microsoft Office v 16 (i.e. version number 16.0 and later).

The first thing to note is that you say that 'I did set a VBA reference to "Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library"'

If that is the case, it looks like you are actually using Mac Office 2011. AFAIK, even if you have both Mac Office 2011 and a later version installed, the Tools->References dialog box in the Visual Basic Editor only offers you the equivalent versions of Word/Office/etc. i.e. from Word 2011 (Office 14.x) you only see Excel 2011 (Office 14.x) and so on.

If so, supporting Mac Office 2011 has arguably become *too hard*. It's probably several years "out of support" from Microsoft's point of view. The latest version of MacOS(X) that I've run it on is MacOSX High Sierra, also several years old. MacOS(X) has made quite radical security-related changes that definitely affect Office 16.x and are even more likely to affect the older Office 14.x.

UPDATE: I just tried to install Office 2011 on Mac Osx Catalina and it wouldn't install, which suggests that it won't work on Catalina, Big Sur, Monterey, or any ARM-based version of Mac Os. If you are actually using an up-to-date version of Mac OS, and Office 365,  and are seeing references to Office 14.x in Tools->References, it seems to me that there is something fundamentally wrong with your installation and that you might have to remove an old version of Office before you can make progress.

And of course we've had ARM-based Mac Silicon for a few years now. I haven't explored much, but it seems, not surprisingly, that some Office VBA, works differently on ARM than Intel.

Just bear in mind that if you read this "Answer," and comment, I can't respond via the comments - you'd have to look for changes to this post.