# Runtime Error 4198 when running VBA code to fill Word document from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, macos, replace, ms-word

I am working on a VBA code in Excel on MacOS that fills values in a Word document. The code is designed to loop through a list of Word documents in a specified path, open each document, and fill content controls with corresponding values from an Excel worksheet.

However, I encountered two issues that I need help with:

1. Initially, I received an error related to the Word application when running the code "Can't start Word Application". However, after restarting, the error disappeared. I would like to understand the possible cause of this error and if there are any preventive measures I should take.
2. After successfully creating the Word application and opening the document, I encountered a runtime error 4198, stating that the command failed. I would appreciate guidance on how to resolve this error and successfully fill the content controls in the Word document.

Thank you for your assistance!

```vb
Sub FillContentControls_MAC()

   Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
   Dim FilePath As String
   Dim NewFilePath As String
   Dim blnRunning As Boolean

   Dim fileList As String
   Dim fileName As Variant

   Dim CCName As String
   Dim CellValue As String
   Dim i As Long

   Dim WordApp As Object, WordDoc As Object
   Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
   PS = Application.PathSeparator

   FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & PS

   fileList = ""

   ' Get a list of Word documents in the specified path
   fileName = Dir(FilePath & "*.docx")
   Do While fileName <> ""
       fileList = fileList & fileName & ";"
       fileName = Dir
   Loop


   fileList = Left(fileList, Len(fileList) - 1)


   'For MAC
   On Error Resume Next
       Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
       If WordApp Is Nothing Then
             MsgBox "Can't start Word Application.", vbExclamation
             Exit Sub
       End If
   On Error GoTo 0

   With WordApp
       .Visible = True

       For Each fileName In Split(fileList, ";")

           'Open
           Set WordDoc = .Documents.Open(FilePath & fileName, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=True)
           If WordDoc Is Nothing Then
               MsgBox "Cannot open:" & vbCr & FilePath, vbExclamation
               .Quit: Set WordApp = Nothing: Exit Sub
           End If

           'Fill
           For i = 3 To WS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

               CCName = WS.Cells(i, "A").Value
               CellValue = WS.Cells(i, "B").Value

               WordDoc.Content.Find.Execute FindText:="[" & CCName & "]", ReplaceWith:=CellValue, Replace:=wdReplaceAll

           Next i

           'Save
           NewFilePath = Left(FilePath & fileName, InStrRev(FilePath & fileName, ".") - 1) & "_Filled.docx"
           WordDoc.SaveAs2 fileName:=NewFilePath

           WordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
       Next fileName

       .Quit
   End With

   Set WordDoc = Nothing
   Set WordApp = Nothing

   Beep
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Are we supposed to just guess which line causes the error?

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I think its `.find.Execute`

Comment: When the error comes up, click the Debug button, then in the immediate window enter `? CCName, CellValue`.

Comment: @z32a7ul so you are suggesting that the error may occur due to the `find text` OR `replace text`?

Comment: I'm not suggesting anything. I recommend investigating these parameters because they are on the line that raises the error. I would check if they contain special characters that can be interpreted as part of a (potentially ill-formed) regex. Then I would have a look at the settings in the Find Window.

Comment: 2. Why use the square brackets（"[]"）? `FindText:="[" & CCName & "]",` 
1. Did you reinstall Word or repair the Office/MS 365 ?

Comment: For the problem when starting Word, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64071777/how-to-save-word-document-using-excel-vba-on-mac-os/64090595#64090595 (It doesn't provide a solution, more a description of what happens. I am not convinced that there is a solution.) For the problem with find.replace, if you have not made a reference to Microsoft Word in VBE Tools->References, wdreplaceAll will be 0 when you need it to be 2, but I do not get errors here as long as there is at least one CC text/placeholder containing "[" & CCName & "]" for each excel row.

Comment: @OscarSun - it is common practice to enclose prompt text in square brackets.

Comment: I made an experiment: `CCName = "a-1"` and `CellValue = "b"` makes it fail if `MatchWildcards:=True` is added (or is somehow saved as a default setting), however the error code in this case is 5590 (The Find What text contains a range that is not valid.).

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt As I know, the square brackets just apply to the wildcard mode find. Is it necessary for the ordinary situation?<https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find.execute>

Comment: @OscarSun - *"Is it necessary for the ordinary situation?"* - Yes, if the text you are looking for is enclosed in square brackets, as is common for prompt text. There is no indication the OP is doing a wildcard search.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Then I just am afraid of the OP is under the improper use of square brackets, unless the object he is looking for is the string with square brackets

Comment: @OscarSun *”unless the object he is looking for is the string with square brackets”* - that is precisely what the OP is looking for. As the question makes clear the OP wants to replace the prompt text of some content controls.

Comment: @VBAbyMBA I just wonder whether the "command failed" actually happened somewhere else - perhaps when executing either a Dir command (Dir is very old, and I can imagine many things that might cause it to fail, especially on Mac) or the SaveAs2. With any luck you should be able to *step through* your code in the VBE and find out.