# Quit method not closing MS Word/MacOS

Tags: excel, vba, macos, ms-word

I have an excel spreadsheet containing code which is meant to loop through a list of Word files to extract information.  Each loop needs to open the file, get the data and then close the file and quit the Word application before looping again.

I can close the file but not quit the application.  When it tries to open the next file when it loops, I get an automation error because the application is still open in the background (as shown by a little dot under Word icon in the dock)

I tried a separate simpler sub to test open/close/quit sequence and the same thing happens:

```
Sub CloseWord()

            Dim WordApp as Object

            Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            DoEvents
            WordApp.Visible = True
            WordApp.Activate
            
            WordApp.Documents.Open 'Word file
        
            WordApp.Documents.Close
                                    
            WordApp.Quit
            
            Set WordApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

This code runs without error but Word stays open in the background.

It gets weirder:
If I run the code the first time, it runs without error but leaves Word open in the background.  I then close word manually and re-run the code and I get the automation error but it still opens word.  I then end the code on the error message box and close Word manually again.  Running the code a 3rd time gets it to work without error, but again leaving Word in the background.

I have repeated this procedure dozens of times, trying to delay after closing Word manually or delaying between steps of code and it is exactly the same every time - even if I manually close Word after the 1st running of code, I will still get an automation error message.  After manually closing Word a second time, the code runs ok.  This makes no sense! The code runs to completion the first time so there should be no lingering variables in the memory.

Do I need to get a windows machine? That's how desperate I am at this point.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the Answer by user12750785 at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64071777/how-to-save-word-document-using-excel-vba-on-mac-os/64090595#64090595 (even though the question is about a slightly different thing). I *think* the situation is more or less the same now (your CreateObject caused the same exception on the current version of Office on my Mac here). It's possible that Microsoft have posted something useful recently but I've given up looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't replicate the issue - the code you posted works fine on my machine (Win 10), even when looped.

Here's an alternative that might help.

Instead of opening and closing the entire Word app with each loop, keep it open, run through all of your documents, and only close Word once the loop is finished.

```
Sub CloseWord()

    Dim WordApp As Object
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        WordApp.Visible = True
        
    'Create and display Word once, rather than every loop.
        
    Dim Index As Long
    For Index = 0 To 5
    
        'Open a file
        Dim WordDoc As Object
        Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\TestDoc.docx")
        
        ' Code to extract data goes here
        
        
        'Then close the file
        WordDoc.Close
        
    Next Index

    'After all documents are looped, close word.
    WordApp.Quit
    
End Sub
```

If it works for you, it has the added benefit of being significantly faster.

Comment: That does work thanks.  But I kept getting automation errors further in my code when accessing tables, rows etc in the word document.  From my search online, it seems like VBA office automation in macOS is more trouble than its worth so I've switched to doing this on windows